# Oracle 11 Selecting largest of a group

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to select the largest action of each serial and list the action number and serial number for each serial.

Desired results:

```
Serial    Action
-----------------
 14       1201
 101      29   


create table listings(serial number(10), action number(10))

Insert into listings(serial, action)
Values ('14', '102');

Insert into listings(serial, action)
Values('14', '1201');

Insert into listings(serial, action)
Values('101', '28');

Insert into listings(serial, action)
Values('101', '29');

Insert into listings(serial, action)
Values('101', '22');
```

I thought this would return the needed data, but get the not a single-group group function. Several variation placing group by clause all return the same error:

```
select *
  from (select max(action),  
               serial
          from listings 
         order by 2 desc)
 where rownum < 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you have to use the `GROUP BY` clause...

```
select serial, max(action) 
from listings 
group by serial;
```

- [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6482/6)

If you only want to get the top 2, ordered by serial:

```
select * from
  (select serial, max(action) as MAX_ACTION
  from listings 
  group by serial
  order by serial)
where ROWNUM <=2;
```

- [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6482/8)

**What does `GROUP BY` do?**

Surprisingly, it groups the results together, and applies the aggregate functions on the groups. This has some restrictions:

- you can only have non aggregated columns in the results that are listed in the `GROUP BY` clause

  - even if they are practically unique for each row
- I recall Oracle not permitting the use of column name aliases in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. If you have for example a `TRUNC`-ed `DATE` to be used in there - you have to repeat the expression...

**Recommended reading**

[Oracle Aggregate functions (11g R2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm)